# Hibernate inheritance mapping annotation with inheritance type SINGLE_TABLE and discriminator column from different table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, inheritance, hibernate-mapping

I have the below schema in the database.

```
Table1 : 
     Purchase_Type
         purchase_type_id
         purchaseType

Table2 :
     Purchases
         purchase_id
         amount
         purchase_type_id
```

I want to use the hibernate "Single table" inheritance of hibernate for the Purchases entity and the subclass would be based on the "purchaseType" in Purchase_Type table which is referred from "Purchases" table by the "purchase_type_id" foreign key. How can I achieve this?
Is it possible to refer to a column in a separate table for the discriminator column in "SINGLE Table" inheritance strategy?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchases")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="purchase_type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "None")
public class Purchases {

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("xyz")
public class PurchaseType1 extends Purchases {
}
```

I want the "purchase_type" attribute of annotation @DiscriminatorColumn in Purchases to refer to "purchaseType" in "Purchase_Type" table. The attribute in @DiscriminatorValue to refer to the appropriate "purchaseType" value in "Purchase_Type" table.

Comment: It would be good if you can share what mappings you have tried and ask what problem you are facing.

Comment: I have added the hibernate mappings I have used!!!

Comment: Any idea how we can do it?